# Erlang Internationalization of a web app?

Tags: internationalization, erlang

I'm looking to internationalize strings in an Erlang web app. I came across [Gettext on trapexit](http://wiki.trapexit.org/Gettext_-_An_internationalization_package.). Any other suggestions as to how to externalize strings in an Erlang app?

Comment: Erlang Gettext currently lives here: https://github.com/etnt/gettext

Answer (score 5, accepted):

gettext has been in daily use since 2003.
Actually, today at the EUC in Stockholm, a tool named POlish was presented that is built on top of gettext. POlish helps with coordinating the translation efforts. See a demo here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UdhE2YOkBCU you'll find POlish (and gettext) at github.

Comment: Cool - thanks. Was't sure if gettext was it or there were other alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

ohh.. this is really old stuff.

I would use Erlectricity (https://github.com/mojombo/erlectricity) and send out strings to Ruby. Right tool for the right job.

If you want to stick to Erlang see whats the status of Zotonic (it is quite rich in this kind of stuff framework). http://zotonic.com/

Comment: I take back 'old stuff'. Trapexit and junglerl make me think so.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it personally but the last time someone asked this question I found this, which appears to be maintained:
https://github.com/etnt/gettext

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, but I just released yet another gettext library for Erlang https://github.com/seriyps/gettexter .

It have some advantages:

- Support for plural forms
- GNU gettext compatibility (eg, you can use standard `xgettext` to extract strings from `.erl` to `.pot`)
- Comments for translators
- Fast string lookup (no message passing, `O(1)`)
- Fupport for namespaces (domains). So, you can translate library applications and don't worry about clashes / conflicts.

It's in beta now, but already runs in production.